# Imports and references required to use LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have never used LINQ before, and I am getting an error in an application that does use it.  This is a VB.NET (.NET 2.0) project in Visual Studio 2008.

Here is the offending code:

```
Dim orderedRows = From r In resultRows Order By r.FIELDNAME Select r
```

And here is the error (names changed to something generic, but otherwise accurate):

```
Expression of type '1-dimensional array of 
Company.OurLibrary.FunctionalArea.Library.StoredProcStuff.USP_MYPROC.ResultRow'
is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly
reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.
C:\project\filename.vb
```

So I recognize that I need to import LINQ libraries.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) led me to add "Imports System.Linq" to the file, but that is an unresolved reference.  Based on the same link, I figured I needed to add a reference to "System.Core" to my project, but it is not listed as an available option when I try to add a reference (nor is it already checked).

I feel sure I'm missing something basic.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

**TL;DR: What do I need for LINQ to work?**

Comment: So if you've got the target assembly set to .Net3.0 or greater, has the system got .NET 3.0 or later installed? Otherwise, can you not add it to the project references?

Comment: @drachenstern: The system does have .NET 3.5 installed, and 4.0 as well, for that matter.  But the target for this application is 3.5.

Comment: What do you mean by “VB.NET (version 2.0)”? The version of VB shipped with VB 2008 was VB 9, not 2 (VB2 ran on DOS).

Comment: @Konrad: he probably meant to say .NET 2.0. Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: based on the comments targeting .NET 2.0 and attempting to use System.Linq would result in a compiler error as follows:

> Namespace or type specified in the
>   Imports 'System.Linq' doesn't contain
>   any public member or cannot be found.

To change the targeted framework version go to the project's Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options... set the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 3.5" and recompile.

In case using .NET 3.5 is not feasible then you can use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to make use of LINQ to Objects while targeting the .NET 2.0 framework.

Comment: @Ahmad Mageed: Thanks for the advice.  All three of those Imports give me this error:Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. I don't see System.Data.DataSetExtensions as available to reference, though I do have that .DLL file on my system at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5"

Comment: @Joseph are you sure you're building against .NET 3.5? Go to your project's Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options... is the Target Framework set to ".NET Framework 3.5"?

Comment: @Joseph I was able to get an identical message by targeting .NET 2.0 with `Imports System.Linq` included. Targeting .NET 3.5 worked fine for me. At this point I am pretty sure `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: @Ahmad: You are correct.  This project is actually targeting .net 2.0.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Joseph no problem. Were you able to get it working after targeting .NET 3.5?

Comment: woohoo I was right again, he was targeting the wrong framework ... See my first comment on the question :D

Comment: @Ahmad, changing the project to .net 3.5 is not an option at this time due to client constraints.  If I change it to 3.5 then a lot of other stuff breaks.  Any thoughts on getting it to work under 2.0?

Comment: @drachenstern should've posted an answer :) It took awhile to go back to the root cause of the issue.

Comment: lol, I saw that it took time ... I really wasn't concerned about the points tho, never have been (or I'ld be clear of 3k by now, to be sure)

Comment: @JosephStyons ~ Why not? You do realize that .NET 3.5 runs on the .NET 2.0 runtime, right? The only thing that has to happen is you have to include those libraries you need with your code. (if you can't install them to the GAC on the target machine)

Comment: @Joseph in that case you should read about [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx). You would still target .NET 2.0 and benefit from LINQ to Objects but not LINQ to SQL or LINQ to XML. This should be a perfectly fine choice. If for whatever reason you can't go for it then you'll need to determine how LINQ heavy the app is and perhaps convert them (manually) to their equivalent traditional code.

Comment: Additionally, ReSharper (from JetBrains) would be able to help you refactor and remove the code that LINQ relies upon.